# Print Screen key not working

Tags: 18.04, gnome, keyboard, budgie

Upon pressing the `Print Screen` key, bell sound is heard, instead of taking a screenshot. I have `gnome-screenshot` installed on my device.

Comment: Did you check in Pictures folder?

Comment: No pictures in Pictures folder.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add what you expect to happen when you press the key.

Comment: Same problem here. When I press Maj+Impr, I see my cursor changes so I can take a screenshot of a part of my screen but sometimes I hear a bip sound which indicates it didn't work and sometimes a bip sound which indicates it should have worked. But in both cases, my picture folder is empty. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely, the <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> key is associated with copying the screenshot to the clipboard. So, you need to paste the image from the clipboard to any application which supports images.

If you want to change this behaviour, launch **Settings**, go to **Keyboard shortcuts**. Look for the screenshots section. See whether the <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> key has been associated with any action or not. If not, click on **Save a screenshot to Pictures** and set it to the <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> key.

[image]

Comment: A simple solution to a confusing problem. This works on debian as well. Thanks @Puspm.